# Multithreading in c++ on slices of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, memory

I have a question about multithreading on vectors.

```
size_t sz = all_objects.size();
size_t np = config.n_threads;
size_t part = sz / np;
vector<vector<int>> solutions(np);
```

Here is needed to say that I do not know a priori the size of each entry of `solutions`.

Then, I prepare the task for the threads:

```
auto paraTask = [&](size_t start, size_t end, vector<int> &sol) {
                for (size_t l = start; l < end; ++l)
                    fun({all_objects[l]}, sol);
            };
for (size_t i = 0; i < np; i++) {
                size_t start = i * part;
                size_t length = (i + 1 == np) ? sz - i * part : part;
                threads[i] =
                          std::thread(paraTask, start, start + length, std::ref(solutions[i]));
            }
```

The function `fun` write on `sol`.

Afterwards I join the threads:

```
for (auto &&thread: threads) thread.join();
```

I have a couple of questions:

- If I time the parts of the code, it seems that most of the times goes in the joining part. In my understanding this makes sense since the join function ends when all the threads end. Is that correct ?
- I noticed that if I start with 1 thread (so without parallelization) and start studying the scalability, until 4 threads I gain in speed. Then after, going on 8 and 16 threads the computational time increases again. So, why there is this "oscillatory" behaviour?

And in general, is it correct to assume that giving different entries of the same vector to different threads (and furthermore, without having reserved the memory a priori of each entry (vector) of the big vector) we have the threads that waits one another because they are in near parts of memory ? If this is the case, why this happens only after 4 threads and not also before?

EDIT:
A couple of precisations:

1. The threads do not write on same variables, by code design. But I'm not sure if this happens for real, since different threads write on different entries of the same vectors.
2. My architecture is the following:
   CPU - 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700KF @ 3.60GHz
   RAM - 16 GB DDR4
   Windows 11
   Compiler - MS_VS 2022

Comment: I think you have too many questions here. You really only want to ask a single focussed question at a time.

Comment: That said, code looks fine. As for 8->16 you really need to know how many cores and/or hardware threads you have on your system. In general running more sw threads than there are hw threads/cores at the same time isn't more efficient. Check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency for more info. Lastly "near" in memory only really applies to cache line - read about it here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size

Comment: But I reiterate - if you ask a single focussed question then you're likely to get a single focussed answer.

Comment: thanks for the comments. Do you have a guess about the ecreasing time from 1 to 2 to 4 threads, and then an increasing again increasing the threads?

Comment: The problem is that after 4 threads I start going up with the computational time, not after 8

Answer (score 2):

1. You can not scale beyond max cores that you have in your system since each thread directly uses core during all its task. `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` can help to figure out what your system supports.
2. Problem with near parts of memory called `false sharing` and can happen if `vector` element size less then cache line of core. For example thread **A** and **B** hold in cache line end of `vector i` and start of `vector i+1`. **A** can change only `vector i` and **B** only `i+1`. To prevent race on cash line each update from **A** will be sent to **B** and vice versa. But **A** doesn't care about changes **B** did on **i+1** yet it receives these irrelevant updates and forced to wait for them.

Comment: And I could avoid this without knowning a priori the size of each vector i? Is there a way to better manage the memory ?

Comment: You have multiple options to deal with false sharing. From not using  contiguous memory locations (list instead of vector) to making size of vector element greater then cache line.

Comment: ok I have an update. I tried to reserve eahc vector i with the max amount of elements we should have in the final solution, i.e., each thread is reserved surely more space than actually needed. This increasing in time when passing from 4 to 8 threads happens again. So, at least in my understing, this false sharing does not happen anymore. any guess ?

Comment: The reason might be not false sharing.  If you test on same all_objects can happen that for some size of all_objects  all_objects /4 threads covers expenses of spawning thread where  all_objects /8 threads not worth to spawn thread for it.

Comment: sorry, but if I do not have false sharing, then I have not waiting time between threads, therefore should scale better when increasing the number of threads if I stay below my max number of available phisical cores, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, calling `join()` essentially waits for the target thread to finish execution and return; if the target thread never returns, the execution on the current thread calling `join()` will halt (a *deadlock*).
2. Scalability depends on numerous factors including **number of processing cores available, the data structure, the scalability of the code itself, etc**. Assuming that you have a code with perfect linear scalability (i.e. execution speed increases linearly with the addition of each thread), the number of cores available will come into play. if you have less cores than executing threads, the scheduler on the CPU (and OS) has to switch between different threads so all threads get some execution time. This *switch* (called a **thread context switch**) is resource expensive and time consuming, so as the ratio of threads to cores increases, more time is spent switching context than actually executing code, hence the worse scalability. In the scenario that there are enough available cores, we can address data structure. When a core wants to operate on data, it has to fetch that data. If that data is not present on registers, it has to fetch them from the cache, and if not present there, from the memory. Data are fetched in contiguous blocks, called cache lines. To put it simply, the data that has been fetched by a core will not be available to be modified by other cores, so if the data are close enough in memory, sometimes the cores will have to wait on other cores to finish their operations on some data. You can even check this in compile time with [std::hardware_destructive_interference_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size).

I tried to explain as simple as i could, some of the point above may not hold true in all situations; and i ignored other factors such as data races and contentions, locks and deadlocks, memory orders, parallel guarantees such as wait-free/lock-free, etc. i strongly recommend reading resources available, such as [Anthony William's C++ Concurrency in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294691) to get a better grasp on concurrency in general and in C++

Comment: I added the architecture and a small comment, maybe can help